# How implements Android in-app-billing

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have integrate Android In-App Billing in my principal activity (MainActivity). The test works !

But, the product to be purchased is the removal of the ads. The ad is implements in a fragment. So, I can't disable ad.

This is my code :

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private static final String TAG = "com.mypackage.inappbilling";

public static final String ITEM_SKU = "test2";

NavigationView navigationView = null;
Toolbar toolbar = null;
IabHelper mHelper;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    //InAppBilling

    String base64EncodedPublicKey = "@string/base64";
    // compute your public key and store it in base64EncodedPublicKey
    mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                // Oh no, there was a problem.
                Log.d(TAG, "Problem setting up In-app Billing: " + result);
            }
            // Hooray, IAB is fully set up!
        }
    });
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent data)
{
    if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode,
            resultCode, data)) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}

IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener
        = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result,
                                      Purchase purchase)
    {
        if (result.isFailure()) {

            // Handle error
            return;
        }
        else if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU)) {
            consumeItem();

        }

    }
};



public void consumeItem() {
    mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mReceivedInventoryListener);
}

IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mReceivedInventoryListener
        = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
                                         Inventory inventory) {

        if (result.isFailure()) {
            // Handle failure
        } else {
            mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(ITEM_SKU),
                    mConsumeFinishedListener);
        }

    }

};

IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener =
        new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
            public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase,
                                          IabResult result) {

            }
        };



@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_agenda) {
        //Set the fragment initially

        MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_cadena) {

        mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, ITEM_SKU, 10001,
                mPurchaseFinishedListener, "mypurchasetoken");


    } else if (id == R.id.nav_apropos) {
        //Set the fragment initially
        AproposFragment fragment = new AproposFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    } 

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mHelper != null) mHelper.dispose();
    mHelper = null;
}
```

MainFragment.java

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;


public static AdView adView;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private View rootView;




public MainFragment() {

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    StartProgress();
    updateInterface();



    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }


    return rootView;



}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {







    swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
    swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    swipeLayout.setColorSchemeColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary),
            getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark), getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));


}




private void updateInterface() {


    if (purchase.getSku().equals(MainActivity.ITEM_SKU)) {

        displayAd(false);
    } else {

        displayAd(true);
    }
}




public void displayAd(boolean state) {

    if (state) {
        if (adView == null) {

            // Google has dropped Google Play Services support for Froyo
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
                adView = (AdView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.adViewCardItem);

                AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                adView.loadAd(adRequest);
            }
        }
    } else {


        if (adView != null) {
            adView.destroy();
            adView = null;
        }
    }
}



@Override
public void onRefresh() {


    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {



            swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }, 2000);


}

public void StartProgress() {
    new AsyncProgressBar().execute();
}



private class AsyncProgressBar extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    protected ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        dialog.setMessage("...");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //duration of progressbar
        SystemClock.sleep(1000);

        return null;
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void useless) {
      .....
    }
}
```

}

I'm stuck on this part of code :

```
private void updateInterface() {


if (purchase.getSku().equals(MainActivity.ITEM_SKU)) {

    displayAd(false);
} else {

    displayAd(true);
}
```

}

How can I appeal to the variable " purchase" my MainActivity.java ? Or maybe this is not the right method ? Can you please enlighten me on this?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I chose an intermediate solution : I created two fragments , one with the pub , and without advertising.

When the user makes the purchase , it is then the ad-free fragment starts.

Here the change of my code :

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private static final String TAG = "com.mypackage.inappbilling";

  public static final String ITEM_SKU = "test2";

NavigationView navigationView = null;
Toolbar toolbar = null;
IabHelper mHelper;
 boolean mIsPremium = false;
boolean mIsUserPremium = false;
boolean searchAllowed = false;



  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(
            "com.xxxxxx", 0);
    mIsPremium = prefs.getBoolean("premium", false);




    if (mIsPremium) {

        MainFragmentDisAd fragment = new MainFragmentDisAd();

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        } else {
        MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }


   //InAppBilling

   String base64EncodedPublicKey = "@string/base64";
   // compute your public key and store it in base64EncodedPublicKey
    mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

     mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
                       @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
                       public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult     result) {
                                   if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                                       // Oh no, there was a problem.
                   Log.d(TAG, "Problem setting up In-app Billing: " + result);

                                   }

                // Hooray, IAB is fully set up. Now, let's get an inventory of

               Log.d(TAG, "Setup successful. Querying inventory.");
          mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);


                               }
                           }
          });
           }


           @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                            Intent data)
      {
        if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode,
        resultCode, data)) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     }
     }

        IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener
       = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result,
                                  Purchase purchase)
     {
    if (result.isFailure()) {

        // Handle error
        return;
    }
    if (!verifyDeveloperPayload(purchase)) {
            complain("Erreur lors de l'achat. Authentification non reconnue.");

            return;

        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Purchase successful.");

        if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU)) {
            // bought the premium upgrade!
            Log.d(TAG, "It's ok.");
            alert("You are premiul");
            mIsPremium = true;
            SharedPreferences prefs = getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences(
                    "com.xxxxx", 0);
            prefs.edit().putBoolean("premium", true).apply();


         }
       };



       public void consumeItem() {
      mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mReceivedInventoryListener);
   }

      IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new      IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
    @Override
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
                                         Inventory inventory) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Inventory is finish.");
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            complain("Echec" + result);

            return;
        }

    /*if (inventory.hasPurchase(PREM_SKU)) {

        mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(PREM_SKU), null);
    }*/

        Log.d(TAG, "Inventory is ok.");


        Purchase premiumPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(ITEM_SKU);
        mIsPremium = (premiumPurchase != null && verifyDeveloperPayload(premiumPurchase));
        Log.d(TAG, "User is " + (mIsPremium ? "PREMIUM" : "NOT PREMIUM"));
        if (mIsPremium) {
            searchAllowed = true;
            mIsUserPremium = true;
            Log.d(TAG, "you must be premium...");
            SharedPreferences prefs = getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences(
                    "com.xxxx", 0);
            prefs.edit().putBoolean("premium", true).apply();


        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Initial inventory query finished; enabling main UI.");


    }


     };

    IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener =
    new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
        public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase,
                                      IabResult result) {

        }
    };



    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
     public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
     int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_agenda) {


        if (mIsPremium) {

            MainFragmentDisAd fragment = new MainFragmentDisAd();

            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        } else {
            MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();

            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }
} else if (id == R.id.nav_cadena) {

    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, ITEM_SKU, 10001,
            mPurchaseFinishedListener, "mypurchasetoken");


} else if (id == R.id.nav_apropos) {
    //Set the fragment initially
    AproposFragment fragment = new AproposFragment();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

} 

   @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
if (mHelper != null) mHelper.dispose();
mHelper = null;
 }
```

It's good for me, it works!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you use [TrivialDrive](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing) example, check how premium purchase is implemented (find usages `mIsPremium`).

```
// Do we have the premium upgrade
Purchase premiumPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_PREMIUM);
mIsPremium = (premiumPurchase != null && verifyDeveloperPayload(premiumPurchase));
```

Disable ads by this variable.

Comment: thank you. 
I took the following example [link](https://github.com/delaroy/InAppBilling/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/delaroystudios/inappbilling/InAppBillingActivity.java). 
However , I don't understand how I can call my method of checking the purchase in my fragment.

Comment: After `mHelper.startSetup()` done a callback `mGotInventoryListener` will be called and you can safely use `mIsPremium`.